# How to update profiles as part of push upgrades?

Tags: managed-package, partner, package-install, push-upgrade

We currently have a managed package that can be installed in customer orgs using a link. Upon installation, the customers have the option to choose what profiles in the org map to what profile in the package:
[image]

This is helpful when installing a new version has new fields/components and profiles are configured correctly. This would save admins the configuration of the profiles after upgrade. Now, we want to use push upgrades and want to be able to update profiles as part of the upgrade but I do not see a way to do that. Does that mean we should get admins involved to upgrade profiles after? or is there a better way?